# How to make perfboard circuits more compact

Tags: operational-amplifier, surface-mount, prototyping, active-filter, protoboard

So, I've been working on my prosthetic limb for quite some time, and I've sorta bumped into a few problems, while the circuits I've made work, they don't fit inside the arm. Mostly because I have tons of opamps (around 28 for a state variable filter, it has settable Q, so I couldn't resist, but I've used quad opamps), and the solder job has been a nightmare. I need to fit it in a small space, and I'm okay with components protruding up and down the board. Is there some way I can me my circuits more compact? I'm thinking of using smd insted of DIPs, but I want a few more options..

Comment: Thought about using real manufactured PCBs with smd parts? much much smaller...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes, but it'd take far too long to get delivered (I think a month or so), and also, I'm pretty much hitting the budget of this project, so I can't really spend anymore

Comment: So 28 opamps do not make you hit the budget but a few bucks for a two layer pcb at some crappy chinese fabhouse do? and where do you live that they need a month to get stuff to you?

Comment: If making a board isn't feasible, you don't have many options. The only thing you can do is basically layout your perfboards as densely as possible, which means your soldering job is going to be even worse. You can try deadbugging and stacking chips, but again, soldering everything isn't going to be fun. Also, consider moving the signal processing into the digital domain as much as possible to reduce the analog component count.

Comment: I live in India, and I bought 80 opamps for $2, so yeah.. (TL074s to be specific). Oh, BTW, the boards cost far more than just a few dollars, It's more like $20

Comment: @uint128_t There really isn't much. It's got an EMG signal acquisition circuit with an instrumental amp per sensor, and I have 7 of those, and then I filter each of them to remove the 60Hz hum and higher frequency garbage, and then they're fed to an MCU and it drives a few servos..

Comment: You should be upping your game to a microcontroller/DSP platform capable of doing the filtering, and then 28 op amps get replaced by one chip

Comment: @ScottSeidman Any suggestions? I've been in the digital domain for the majority of my hobbyist life.. I know hot use AVRs and ARMs, if that helps you.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Forgot to mention that I need to filter 7 signals independently

Comment: That really doesn't change much

Comment: @ScottSeidman What do you mean?

Comment: You just use a bigger/badder microcontroller/DSP.

Comment: Any microcontroller/DSP powerful enough to do that is surely going to be SMD, not to mention the signals/clock will need a proper PCB

Comment: @crocboy I'm pretty good at soldering smd, even on perboard, just it takes time..

Comment: Is this a one-off project for some particular person to use or a prototype for something you might make for many people? If it's the second one, leave the perfboard outside the arm for the demo. Use the demo to get funding/grants/... to build the miniaturized version on a built-for-the-purpose PCB.

Comment: Soldering a TQFP or QFN package on perfboard is impossible without using a breakout board or something similar... not trying to discourage you, just being realistic

Comment: It's a one-off project, I might mass manufacture it, but really I'd need to turn to kickstarter for that, and I don't really have that kinda time, being a 3rd year high schooler

Comment: @crocboy Not quite, you can quite easily solder it if you use some kapton tape and enamel wire, but you'll definitely need some solder wick

Comment: @crocboy, I've deadbugged a QFN or two, and thats way harder than a tqfp.

Comment: The advantages provided by a PCB are just too numerous for me to even consider doing that stuff

Comment: @crocboy I won't deny that, but it'd take a bit too long for me to get a pcb shipped.

Answer (score 7):

The ultimate answer is to use SMD components on a PCB - the parts are smaller, and using traces instead of wires will reduce stray capacitance; this can have a large effect in sensitive circuits.  I understand your reluctance to use a PCB because it is more work and more expensive initially - however, in the long run it sounds like the only way you will get what you want.

You can use perfboard and wire everything together manually, but debugging those circuits is very difficult.

Comment: Well I would've if I wanted to produce it, but it's sort of a project so I'm gonna have to stick with 1, and ordering 10 pcbs for that sounds wasteful

Comment: In the end, that's just how it it, unless you want to try to etch your own PCB.  I'm not sure what fab houses ship to India, but I use OSH Park or DirtyPCB

Comment: It'd be a routing nightmare to create a single sided board with the no of components I'm using. And dirtyPCBs take a lot longer to ship than I'd like

Comment: With a two-layer board you have the top and bottom layers to route traces - also you can use zero-ohm links to cross two traces on the same layer

Comment: but you can't really make one at home, that's the problem

Comment: If you absolutely have to make it at home and can't use a PCB, I would highly recommend reducing the device count by using filter IC's, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may not thank me for this, but you can look into a technique from back in the dark ages, [cordwood construction](http://boldport.blogspot.com/2014/03/a-tribute-to-cordwood-construction-of.html).

[image]

This will allow you very high component densities, and if you're just doing signal processing you should be able to get away with the thermal issues which arise with this approach.

The reason I say you may not thank be for it is that, once assembled, it's a stone b**ch to troubleshoot. You must be meticulously organized and focused in order to put one of these things together, and your spatial perception must be first rate in order to figure out how to make the connections.

But it does make very compact assemblies.

Comment: I'm using acitve op amp based filters, and this method wouldn't really solve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

You want fast, cheap, and small. If you are dead set on using perf board, pick two of those. If you want all three, you will very likely be forced to get a PCB, whether you like it or not. That's just a fact of engineering. I understand that PCB money doesn't flow from one person's pocket as easily as it might from another, but unfortunately, that's the way it is. If your circuit works, then just strap the big clunky thing to the outside of the prosthetic. Its a prototype, right?

Comment: Yeah, but, perfection...

Comment: The very thought of putting a perf board in a final enclosure for any project shows that it is not complete. I spent a whole lot of time as a teenager hacking things together on perf board. If your idea has legs, either you or someone else will find a way to fund it. And if you're not getting contracted to complete this task, then I highly doubt there is any real problem with waiting to get a PCB shipped to you while you continue to work on the perf board version.

Comment: I need to complete it for the Google Science Fair